# How to hide keyboard by touch in the screen if all my main view is cover by another views?

Tags: ios, swift

I cant touch in my main view, I have few other views on him.

this func :

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
   self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

dose'nt help me..

is there any func?

Answer (score 0):

If you know which View is focused you can call resignFirstResponder() on it

Comment: where? myView.resignFirstResponder()  ?

Comment: Well, I've to admit I missed the point, you're right. If your view is totally covered by input field your could put your call in textfieldShouldReturn